# roll up similar pages into some kind of "page type"

Tags: google-analytics

I've got an app that has a /restaurants URL, which lists restaurants.
Each restaurants has a URL like: /restaurants/

So, GA reports pages views like:
/restaurants
/restaurants/1234
/restaurants/3456

This means that when I view the "Behavior Flow" tab in GA, there are hundreds of little boxes for each individual restaurant.  It would be more informative (in some cases) to lump all 'restaurant' pages together.

However -- I do *not* want to do away with the granular URL identifiers for each different restaurant all together, because that it is useful in some other reporting.

So, should I be passing some different data with each page view?  Should I use events?  Ideally, this is a change to the code that is reporting data so that I don't have to add some configuration change to every view that uses this data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use Content Grouping, which can be set on View level. In your case, use rule definition for creating a page group of restaurants, which can be later used as a dimension in your reports. E.g. create a page group Restaurants, and define a rule for Page containing /restaurants/

This way, you won't need to alter basic data collection, and you'll still access per restaurant details in Page reports.

However, if you'd have more than 5 of these content groups, you might consider a different logic for grouping.

Comment: Yea, I'd strongly prefer to not fix this with some kind of view-level change.  The raw data is split into multiple views with filters, so that change would have to be made in many places.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that preference of yours. What about adding one ore more custom dimensions, that could be used to indicate similar content grouping on property level? E.g. is_restaurant = Y/N or venue_type = restaurant, or something similar, based on your other considerations. This could be used as a dimension in your reports.